# BigQuery. Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is a query which results in this error:
Query Failed
Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

```
select date
       ,isdepositor
       ,category 
       ,(select distinct dd from unnest(d.subcategory) dd) subcategory
       ,dau
from(
       select date
       ,isdepositor
       ,'Level' as Category
       ,array(select 'Daily' union all select 'Weekly' union all select 'Monthly') subcategory
       , dau 
       from DWH.vT_DAU
) d
```

DWH.vT_DAU is a view, where DAU is calculated for each date and boolean field 'isdepositor'.

I need to create custom fields 'Category' and 'Subcategory' where the same for each 'date' and 'isdepositor' DAU will be displayed.

I found some similar question regarding this bigquery error here, however, any solution didn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Managed to solve this using UNNEST in JOIN. However, would appreciate if anyone has ideas on how to UNNEST in SELECT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to create custom fields 'Category' and 'Subcategory' where the same for each 'date' and 'isdepositor' DAU will be displayed.

Below does exactly this

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date
  ,isdepositor
  ,'Level' AS Category
  ,subcategory
  , dau 
FROM `DWH.vT_DAU`
CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT 'Daily' subcategory UNION ALL SELECT 'Weekly' UNION ALL SELECT 'Monthly')
```

above is equivalent to below - which is most likely what you ended up (based on your comment)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date
  ,isdepositor
  ,'Level' AS Category
  ,subcategory
  , dau 
FROM `DWH.vT_DAU`
, UNNEST(['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly']) subcategory
```

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail! Did it similarly to your second variant